# How not to enter space in an input filed using react

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a to-do app and I don't want 'space' to print when I submit a to do. I tried using the `disabled={input}` on button when submitting since the const input is an empty string but it's not working. Is there any other way so that the space is not printing when submitting a to do?

[image]

```
function App() {


  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([' Take dogs for walk', 'Cook food for breakfast']);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop refresh
    setTodos([...todos, input]) // using spread operator and from input it will store in todos.
    setInput(''); // to clear the input field
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
     
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">Write a Todo</InputLabel>
  <Input value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
</FormControl>
<Button disabled={!input} type='submit' onClick={addTodo} variant="contained">
Add to do
</Button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `!input.trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try conditional to addTodo function.

```
  const addTodo = (event) => {
    if(!input.length || input.trim() === '') return // add here
    ..... other codes
  }
```